# jQuery ajax cross site to get header HTML status

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is for a userscript.

I want to go to a URL and see if it redirects (status 302) or if it returns the OK status (status 200).

The only issue is that the URL is getting blocked by the same-origin-policy so I can't just do an ajax call to get the head.

I'm looking for an efficent way of checking this rather than using YQL/loading the entire page (I am very unfamiliar with this type of stuff).

Comment: You can't do that with JS alone. You'll need to write a PHP script and utilise something like `get_headers()`.

Comment: As you cannot do it with JavaScript alone, please tag a language you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a gateway PHP script on a server that you have access to, which checks the headers sent from the request using [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php). Once you have that info, you can assess it and return some JSON. Now, you just need to call the PHP script using jQuery's AJAX function.

For example, your PHP file might be called `get-status.php` and look like this:

```
<?php

$headers = get_headers( $_REQUEST['url'] );

$parts = explode(' ', $headers[0]); // Matches: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
$status = $parts[1];                // Provides: 200

// Build the response:
$response = new stdClass();
$response->url = $_REQUEST['url'];
$response->date = time();
$response->status = (int) $status;
$response->redirected = ($status == 301 || $status == 302);

// Send response as JSON:
header( ' Content-Type: application/json' );
echo json_encode( $response );

?>
```

Next, you can call `get-status.php` from within jQuery using [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
$.getJSON( 'get-status.php', { url: 'http://www.google.com/' }, function(data) {  

    // Now, data contains the following params:
    // data.url = http://www.google.com/
    // data.date = timestamp of request
    // data.status = 200
    // data.redirected = false

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to the server. I'm doing this with jquery + JS as it's a userscript.

Comment: Then you will need to find a server that you can configure the CORS policy on.